# Getting request param from url

Tags: python, django

I have a url of a type where query string is like this... ?

> next=/contact/200/10626096&back%3DZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUubmxoL2NsYXNzaWZpZWQvYXV0b3M0eDRzL2Fjd>XJhL2NzeGVsLz95ZWFyX19ndGU9JmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JnNlbGxlcl90eXBlPSZpc19zZWFyY2g9MSZraWxvbWV0ZXJz>X19ndGU9JnByaWNlX19ndGU9JnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPUVudGVyK0xvY2F0aW9uJTI4cyUyOStIZXJlJnBsYWNlc19>faWRfX2luPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9MjAxMiZraWxvbWV0ZXJzX19sdGU9JmtleXdvcmRzPSZpc19iYXNpY19zZWFyY2hfd2>lkZ2V0PTAmcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0%3D

I am getting this url in my backend code using `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`
as this one is my referer url not the current one so I can't use `request.get_full_path`.

Now I just want the value of `next` from it which is `/contact/200/10626096` but the problem is that I can't use `request.GET.get('next')` as it is not the current url.

I don't want to use `split('?next=')` type of solutions as I am looking for more pythonic solutions like  `request.GET.get('next')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs('next=/contact/200/10626096&back%3DZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUubmxoL2NsYXNzaWZpZWQvYXV0b3M0eDRzL2FjdXJhL2NzeGVsLz95ZWFyX19ndGU9JmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JnNlbGxlcl90eXBlPSZpc19zZWFyY2g9MSZraWxvbWV0ZXJzX19ndGU9JnByaWNlX19ndGU9JnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPUVudGVyK0xvY2F0aW9uJTI4cyUyOStIZXJlJnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9MjAxMiZraWxvbWV0ZXJzX19sdGU9JmtleXdvcmRzPSZpc19iYXNpY19zZWFyY2hfd2lkZ2V0PTAmcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0%3D')
{'next': ['/contact/200/10626096']}
```